# React bootstrap modal context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap modal. It seems that functions that are called from it have differrent context than functions called from other parts of the component. When I check the value of this.selectedPhone in the function(handleSelect()) that handles selection from a select element, the expected value is there. When I open up the modal and press a button that calls the confirmChange() function, the value in the function is the initial value that I set for this.selectedPhone in constructor.

```
<tr>
    <td>{this.props.todo.name}</td>
    <td>{this.props.todo.version}</td>
    <td><select ref={(select) => {this.newVersion = select}} onChange={this.handleSelect} className="versionInput">
    {this.props.versions.filter(version => version.chain === this.props.todo.chain).map(version =>
      <option selected={version.name===this.selectedPhone} value={version.name}>{version.name}</option>
        ) }
    </select></td>
    <td >{this.props.todo.chain}</td>
    <td >{this.props.todo.store}</td>
    <Modal selectedPhone={this.selectedPhone} onHide={this.props.toggleModal} show={this.props.showModal}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
         <Modal.Title>Change: {this.props.todo.name}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
         <p>Change to:</p><label>{this.props.todo.version}</label>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.confirmChange}>Change</button>
         <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.toggleModal}>Cancel</button>
      </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>
  </tr>
```

Here are the functions bound to the DOM:

```
confirmChange(e){
    console.log(this.selectedPhone);//Always outputs the initial value that is set in the constructor of component
  }
  handleSelect(e){
    this.selectedPhone=e.target.value.slice(0);
   console.log(this.selectedPhone); //The right value output in console
   this.toggleModal();
  }
  toggleModal(){
      this.props.toggleModal();
  }
```

This is the contructor:

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.toggleModal=this.toggleModal.bind(this);
      this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSelect=this.handleSelect.bind(this);
      this.confirmChange=this.confirmChange.bind(this);
      this.newValue=this.newValue;
      this.selectedPhone=this.props.todo.phone.slice(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this problem is that each table row component has a dialog that has its show property bound to redux state... So when opening the dialog via changing the redux state - there were actually as many dialogs open as there were rows in the table, which explains the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the selectedPhone state instead of using a variable.Try using the following way

```
handleSelect(e){
    this.setState({selectedPhone:e.target.value.slice(0)});
   console.log(this.state.selectedPhone);
   this.toggleModal();
  }

confirmChange(e){
    console.log(this.state.selectedPhone);
  }
```

Comment: Tried with state - the state is equal to the initial state in the confirmChange function and doesn't show the newly assigned value